# jhipster giving autoloader error while generating an application

Tags: java, node.js, spring, jhipster

I am working `macOS Big Sur 11.2.3`, with `java version "14.0.1" 2020-04-14`,  `node v16.1.0`, `git version 2.24.3` (Apple Git-128), and `maven`

```
Apache Maven 3.6.3 (cecedd343002696d0abb50b32b541b8a6ba2883f)
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.6.3_1/libexec
Java version: 14.0.1, vendor: N/A, runtime: /usr/local/Cellar/openjdk/14.0.1/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home
Default locale: en_IN, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.16", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

I have installed Jhipster with below command and is successfully installed.

```
sudo npm install -g generator-jhipster
```

But now when I type the command `jhipster` to generate the application in a new project folder, I am getting below error. I have no clue what went wrong and how to resolve this. can any one help me on this please.

```
 Error: editions-autoloader-invalid-engines: The edition had no engines to compare against the environment
        at new Errlop (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/errlop/edition-es5/index.js:61:18)
        at Object.errtion (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/editions/edition-es5/util.js:23:14)
        at isCompatibleEngines (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/editions/edition-es5/index.js:183:19)
        at isCompatibleEdition (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/editions/edition-es5/index.js:250:10)
        at determineEdition (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/editions/edition-es5/index.js:287:4)
        at determineEdition (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/editions/edition-es5/index.js:312:12)
        at solicitEdition (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/editions/edition-es5/index.js:350:16)
        at Object.requirePackage (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/editions/edition-es5/index.js:364:9)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/istextorbinary/index.cjs:4:38)
        at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1109:14) {
      klass: [Function: Errlop] {
        create: [Function (anonymous)],
        isErrlop: [Function (anonymous)],
        ensure: [Function (anonymous)]
      },
      parent: undefined,
      ancestors: [],
      orphanStack: 'Error: editions-autoloader-invalid-engines: The edition had no engines to compare against the environment\n' +
        '    at new Errlop (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/errlop/edition-es5/index.js:61:18)\n' +
        '    at Object.errtion (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/editions/edition-es5/util.js:23:14)\n' +
        '    at isCompatibleEngines (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/editions/edition-es5/index.js:183:19)\n' +
        '    at isCompatibleEdition (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/editions/edition-es5/index.js:250:10)\n' +
        '    at determineEdition (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/editions/edition-es5/index.js:287:4)\n' +
        '    at determineEdition (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/editions/edition-es5/index.js:312:12)\n' +
        '    at solicitEdition (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/editions/edition-es5/index.js:350:16)\n' +
        '    at Object.requirePackage (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/editions/edition-es5/index.js:364:9)\n' +
        '    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/istextorbinary/index.cjs:4:38)\n' +
        '    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1109:14)',
      code: 'editions-autoloader-invalid-engines'
    }
```

Comment: Please try with an LTS version of Node like 14.x

Comment: solved the issue after updating the node version to latest  14.16.1 LTS

Answer (score 2):

Always use an LTS 64-bit version of Node as stated in the [JHipster doc](https://www.jhipster.tech/installation/)